# Search form is not resetting , what is wrong here?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Here is my html

```
<form method="get"  name="searchform" action="urllinkhere">Player:<input size="8" class="reallysmall" name="NAME" type="text">
<input name="L" value="%LEAGUEID%" type="hidden"></form>
```

I have tried both of the following methods and the form won't clear on a page refresh.

```
$('searchform')[0].reset();



var form = document.getElementById("searchform");
form.reset();
```

Comment: As I see, you have set default value: "%LEAGUEID%" to the input. If you are expecting that to clear - it wont. Everything should clear on page refresh even if you do not call anything.

Comment: If you want to reset, use a `reset` button: `<input type="reset">`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your form does not have an id, so this does not work:

```
var form = document.getElementById("searchform");
form.reset();
```

And the jQuery way need to be selected by an id or name:

```
<form method="get"  id="searchform" name="searchform" action="urllinkhere">Player:<input size="8" class="reallysmall" name="NAME" type="text">
<input name="L" value="%LEAGUEID%" type="hidden"></form>


$('#searchform')[0].reset();
```

OR:

```
$('form[name=searchform]')[0].reset();
```

**DEMO**: http://jsfiddle.net/kehu62j6/